# Push notifications only work when logged out

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, push-notification

We've got a phoengap app that receives push notifications. Got quite a wierd one at the moment, when the user is logged out of the app the push notifications work fine. But when they login, it breaks.

I'm wondering if it's re-registering with GCM/Apple and getting a new ID or something when logged in.

I guess the question is, when should I run the following code. At the moment it runs once the user is logged in. Should I run it once ever and then save the ID and never run the register again?

```
 receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

        if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
            pushNotification.register(this.successHandler, this.errorHandler,{"senderID":"1019013414678","ecb":"app.onNotificationGCM"});
        }
        else {

            pushNotification.register(this.tokenHandler,this.errorHandler,{"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"app.onNotificationAPN"});
        }
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    },
    // iOS
    onNotificationAPN: function(event) {
        var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
        console.log("Received a notification! " + event.alert);
        console.log("event sound " + event.sound);
        console.log("event badge " + event.badge);
        console.log("event " + event);
        if (event.alert) {
            navigator.notification.alert(event.alert);

        }

        if (event.sound) {
            var snd = new Media(event.sound);
            snd.play();
        }
    },
    // Android
    onNotificationGCM: function(e) {
        switch( e.event )
        {
            case 'registered':
                if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
                {
                    console.log("Regid " + e.regid);
                  localStorage.setItem("PushID", e.regid)
                  updateID();
                }
                break;

            case 'message':
                // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model
                // of the intermediary push server which must also be reflected in GCMIntentService.java
                alert(e.message);
                break;

            case 'error':
                alert('GCM error = '+e.msg);
                break;

            default:
                alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Comment: Yeh, it was giving a new ID each time the app opened, i stopped it doing that

Comment: Could you elaborate? How exactly?

Comment: If you could answer your own question 'when should I run the following code', it will surely help me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake. I was running this code every time the app opened and it was giving me a new ID. I just kept the ID i had originally and it seems to have worked.